# azure active directory token lifetimes

Tags: azure, timeout, access-token

I'm trying to figure out how to set a token policy that will log a user out of my app after 1 hour.  Looking at the documentation, it doesn't look that straightforward.  How can this be done from the portal ? The examples seem to favour power shell, but surely It can be done from the portal ? Id like to be able to select my app in active directory and set a global policy for every user of that app which sets a max inactive time of 1 hour then logs the user out.  Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, only way currently is to use the v2 modules for PowerShell (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.154) (or the underlying API): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.

You can't set these from the portal yet.